# Layout for virtualisation of 50 desktops

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, citrix, vdi, hardware

We are planning to deploy 50 virtual desktops(for normal users) using thin client hardware and VDI solution(using VMware or Citrix).Currently we have'nt virtualised any of the physical servers.I heard virtualisation of the servers are required for implementing VDI.Can anyone  tell me a rough layout required for the hardware(for server and thin clients) and softwares(including server OS ,licenses etc) for the project.I don't have much knowledge about licensing and hardwares since i am new to the industry.We are thinking of not using SAN storage because these 50 users are mostly using web applications only and they don't have to store any data(also due to the financial constraints).
Thanks.

Comment: Are you, ahem, asking us to design a solution for you? I'm sure there are folks around here who'd do that - for a fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a very open ended question but I'll take a shot

1. You can virtualize your desktops before servers BUT it's actually usually easier to do the servers first - you know them better, they are usually more constant in their load and there is hopefully less complexity as far as installed software is concerned.
2. For the sizing question - Add the RAM in all of the existing systems, This is your #1 likely bottleneck. Next look at disk IO and only after both of those consider CPU.
3. You are going to have to use some kind of storage, I would recommend using SSD disks at least for area storing your boot disk image(s) and any common applications - this will give your users a much nicer experience.

f you are mainly using web based apps I'd look at using terminal servers with thin clients before virtual desktops - it's (usually) a less expensive solution and will look about the same to your end users. Sizing requirements are about the same.

Windows Remote Desktop or Hyper-V both will let you start your set up for testing with out additional licenses (well desktop licenses are required for the desktop OSes, YMMV) but to actually go into production you should talk to your vendors or call someone like CDW.